# If a photon doesn't necessarily travel in a straight line, doesn't it defy the law of cons. of momentum?

Tags: photons, momentum, conservation-laws, quantum-electrodynamics

I just finished reading Richard Feynman's lectures on Quantum Electrodynamics (QED: *The Strange Theory of Light and Matter*) and it fascinated me. However, there's an unanswered question I have from reading it.

If, as Feynman argues, "light doesn't *really* travel only in a straight line; it 'smells' the neighboring paths around it and uses a small core of nearby space" (though it is overwhelmingly likely to appear to be traveling in a straight line over long distances), how does this not defy the law of conservation of momentum? My understanding is that this law applies to light as well, with a momentum defined by p = E/c. If so, light curving would clearly defy it, would it not?

Comment: A path integral is a mathematical object that just happens to describe the physics of an electromagnetic field properly. It does not give you a self-consistent interpretation of quantum mechanics in terms of classical mechanics of point particles that travel on well defined paths. Feynman himself warns against taking the picture of path integrals beyond its range of applicability.

Comment: Ref. to "light curving": When we speak of "wave", momentum is being detected "on both sides of the beam"? As the photon has no mass - is momentum being detected and located in the maxima of the amplitudes which "stray away" from the "middle of the road"? Does the momentum localize at all? Or is it localized by its impact on mass (which by the way, may not be some free electron, according to answer to related question). Amplitudes you see on a wave graph, they just express a periodic change of field, which is not momentum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you've read only QED, this is a highly astute question.

Conservation laws in the quantum world work a little differently from classical conservation grounded on Noether's theorem (there is a kind of quantum analogue in the Ward-Takahashi identity).

If a quantum entity has state $|\psi\rangle$, then conserved quantities are measurement *means* defined by  $\langle\psi|\hat{p}|\psi\rangle$, where $\hat{p}$ is any non-time-varying observable that commutes with the quantum Hamiltonian. The momentum observable is one such observable. This is nicely summarized by [Ehrenfest's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem)  $\mathrm{d}_t\,\langle\psi|\hat{p}|\psi\rangle = \langle\psi|[\hat{H},\,\hat{p}]|\psi\rangle$.

Accordingly, when the photon "sniffs neighboring paths", which is Feynman's lay explanation  for when the photon is in a *superposition* of different momentum eigenstates (going many directions at once), it is only the mean of the momentum measurement that is conserved. No violation of conservation happens simply by dint of there being "many different paths"; it is only the mean measurement we need to look at.